# Bricked openflow switch with U-Boot

Tags: boot

I've got a tricky question and wonder if anyone has a solution to it.

I have an openflow switch here that uses u-boot as bootloader. It has a main Linux system that runs the switch software. Then it also has another backup system, that is used to upgrade the main system, so you don't need to mess with a running system.

The usual upgrade procedure is rename the /boot/uImage, so u-boot can't find it anymore and doesn't autoboot. Now you use u-boot to manually boot into the backup system, which is on /dev/sda2. Now you mount /dev/sda1, where the main system resides. You delete everything off /dev/sda1, pull the new system image and extract it to /dev/sda1. This includes a new /boot/uImage so once you reboot it autoboots into the new system.

My problem is that during all of that something went wrong. I guess there was some file corruption when unpacking the new image.

Now u-boot boots the new image, but that one doesn't fully come up. The main things lacking are the shell when connecting via serial, ssh and telnet, so there is no way of issuing commands to the Linux system.

Also u-boot has a bootdelay of 0, which means I can't abort autoboot.

I tried holding CTRL-C, CTRL-B or CTRL-U during boot (as Google told me to), but none of them aborted autoboot.

Do you have any ideas what else I can try to stop autoboot?

I already had it open, the storage is directly on board, there is no way to disconnect the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite stupid and simple, but Google did not tell me. All I needed to do was to press (not hold) CTRL-C and quickly after that CTRL-U during boot. Might just be that one board, but it worked here.